# Run minecraft server on startup without login

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-task-scheduler, minecraft

I'm using Wakeup Over Lan to start my windows 10 PC and I want my Minecraft server (spigot 1.16.4) when the computer starts. I have a password for my account and don't want to disable it.

so far I have tried:

1. use an exe and used task scheduler to run the exe on startup. "Run whether user is logged on or not" is enabled, as is "Do not store password" and this didn't work.
2. Create second account without password. Same as before except it runs the exe on login. The computer starts and logs into the second account but the server didn't start.

Spigot starts a cmd window to run the server from so I suspect that it can't open this window and therefore doesn't work. Is there any way I can get this to work?

Comment: It needs to be able to run as system, or you need to configure some sort of auto log on.

Comment: @music2myear I'll have a look at running it as a system, or as a service but I don't want to have an auto log on as I want to keep my PC secure

Comment: You can log a non-interactive session if you're running a server. As in: there can be a user logged on without the screen being active, and still requiring a password in order to interact directly. It would be similar to the user being logged on and then locking their desktop

Comment: @music2myear that would work, how would i do that? i don't have any experience with things like this

Answer (score 0):

You need to use scheduled tasks in Windows. For your particular purpose, the event "on bootup" would do the trick, I think. The command (or task) would be the full path to the script which starts the server, with all the arguments. Alternatively, you can use a .bat script as the command. I use this technique to mount network drives whenever I log in, works like a charm.

Start taskschd.msc (from the windows folder) and click around to figure it out.

You can find further and more detaliend instructions here:

https://www.technipages.com/scheduled-task-windows

If the link dies, check out Microsoft documentation and look for the topic "scheduled tasks"